# Problem in passing arguments to constructor of object

Tags: c++

I am practicing to use map in C++, I faced a problem that I provided argument to the constructor but the compiler insists that I did not provide arguments.

This is my code:

```
struct Node
{
public:
    vector<int> state;
    int cost;
    Node * next;
    Node(const vector<int> & table, int cost): state(table), cost(cost), next(nullptr) {}
    Node(const vector<int> & table): state(table), cost(0), next(nullptr) {}
    Node(const Node & node) : state(node.state), cost(node.cost), next(node.next) {}
};

class PriorityQueue
{
private:
    Node * head;
    ...

public:
    ...
    Node pop()
    {
        Node * temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        return *temp;
    }
};

vector<vector<int>> aStarSearch(Problem & p, int (*func)(const vector<int> &))
{  
    ...
    PriorityQueue frontier; 
    Node _node(p.initial);
    frontier.insert(&_node);
    map<vector<int>, Node> reached;
    reached.emplace(p.initial, _node);
    while ( ... ) {
        Node node = frontier.pop();
        vector<Node> children = expand(p, node);
        for (Node child : children) {
            vector<int> s = child.state;
            if (!(reached.count(s)) || child.cost < reached[s].cost) {
                reached[s] = child;
                frontier.insert(&child);
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

The error:

```
8puzzle.cpp:18:5: note: candidate: 'Node::Node(const Node&)'
     Node(const Node & node) : state(node.state), cost(node.cost), next(node.next) {}
     ^~~~
8puzzle.cpp:18:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
8puzzle.cpp:17:5: note: candidate: 'Node::Node(const std::vector<int>&)'
     Node(const vector<int> & table): state(table), cost(0), next(nullptr) {}
     ^~~~
8puzzle.cpp:17:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
8puzzle.cpp:16:5: note: candidate: 'Node::Node(const std::vector<int>&, int)'
     Node(const vector<int> & table, int cost): state(table), cost(cost), next(nullptr) {}
     ^~~~
8puzzle.cpp:16:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
```

When I declare the map as it has two argument of types (vector, Node*), it runs smoothly. Why that difference happens?

I tried to construct a map has key as a vector and a value as a node and need not to use pointer. I were expecting it run well but it did not.

Comment: Using `[]` on a map requires that you have a default constructor. Your `Node` class does not. Add a default constructor to `Node` and you'll be fine. If you read your errors carefully they are all about the map class trying to call a constructor with zero arguments (i.e. `0 provided`) and going through all the constructors you do have and then saying, 'no that one doesn't have zero arguments'.

Comment: An alternative (perhaps better) would be to use `find` instead of `[]` on your map. Because `reached[s]` returns a reference it must add an entry to your map if it doesn't find the key you are looking for. This is why a default constructor is needed, to default construct the value to go with the key it is adding to the map.

Comment: @john It would be even better to go with only a single lookup: `auto emplaceResult = reached.try_emplace(std::move(s), std::move(child)); bool addToFrontier = emplaceResult.second; if (!addToFrontier && (child.cost < emplaceResult.first->second.cost)) { addToFrontier = true; emplaceResult.first->second = std::move(child); } if (addToFrontier) { frontier.insert(&emplaceResult.first->second); }` @Hieu note that `frontier.insert(&child);` likely results in undefined behaviour, since the `child` object gets destroyed after each iteration.